# Get API returning HttpErrorrResponse in angular code with error code 302 and response json wrpaped in error

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I have written a simple GET API which is returning a list of Claim.
The url of the API is 
`http://localhost:8898/claim/v1/claimByClaimNum/' + claimNumber`

Now when I am invoking this through my angular code using `HttpClient`, 
I am getting `HttpErrorResponse`.

I am calling Rest API by the below code in my `Service.ts`

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ClaimResultItem } from '../claim-result/claim-result-item.model';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class ClaimHttpService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getClaimsByClaimNumber(claimNumber: string) {

    this.http.get<ClaimResultItem>
      ('http://localhost:8898/claim/v1/claimByClaimNum/' + claimNumber)
      .subscribe((response => {
        console.log(response.subjectId);
      }
      ));
  }
}
```

When I am calling above method, I am getting below error-

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 302, statusText: "OK", 
url: "http://localhost:8898/claim/v1/claimByClaimNum/1234", ok: false, …}
error: {claimNumber: "1234", claimStatus: "Paid", claimAmount: "125.00", 
claimStartDate: "2019-01-01", claimEndDate: "2019-05-01", …}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, 
lazyInit: ƒ}
 message: "Http failure response for 
http://localhost:8898/claim/v1/claimByClaimNum/1234: 302 OK"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 302
statusText: "OK"
 url: "http://localhost:8898/claim/v1/claimByClaimNum/1234"
 __proto__: HttpResponseBase
 constructor: ƒ HttpErrorResponse(init)
__proto__:
 constructor: ƒ HttpResponseBase(init, defaultStatus, defaultStatusText)
 __proto__: Object
```

It seems that HttpClient is getting the response from the API but still wrapping it in error and returning it in 302 Http code.

```
 error: {claimNumber: "1234", claimStatus: "Paid", claimAmount: "125.00", 
 claimStartDate: "2019-01-01", claimEndDate: "2019-05-01", …}
```

How to remove this error , any pointer will be helpful.

My Rest API is working fine and giving me result when I am invoking it independently through Postman.Also Rest service is Cross origin resource supported.

I am calling the method from component at `onSubmit()` at the click of the button

```js
onSubmit() {
  console.log(this.form.value.claimNumber);
  this.claimHttpService.getClaimsByClaimNumber(this.form.value.claimNumber);
}
```

Comment: How are you sending response to angular from api? Is it in a Ok() method? Please share the API method being invoked.

Comment: are you using any error interceptor in angular side ? if yes , then post the code here

Comment: I am not using any interceptor , simply calling the getClaimsByClaimNumber method from the component.

Comment: I am using RespnseEntity to return the response-  
         @GetMapping("claimByClaimNum/{claimNum}")
  public ResponseEntity<Claim> 
         getClaimByClaimNumber(@PathVariable("claimNum") String claimNum)
 {
  Claim claim = claimService.getClaimByClaimNumber(claimNum);
  ResponseEntity<Claim> response = new ResponseEntity<Claim>(claim,HttpStatus.FOUND);
  return response;
 }